# How can I improve Karma test coverage on config files in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, code-coverage, karma-runner

I have a file `app/routes.coffee`

'use strict'

```
webApp.config [
  '$stateProvider'
  '$urlRouterProvider'
  '$locationProvider'
  ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) ->

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'

    $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
      url: '/'
      views:
        appView:
          templateUrl: '/templates/app/dashboard.html'
    })
    .state('repository', {
      url: '/repository/:repo_host/:username/:name'
      views:
        appView:
          templateUrl: '/templates/app/repository.html'
    })
    .state('profile', {
      url: '/profile'
      views:
        appView:
          templateUrl: '/templates/app/profile.html'
    })
    .state('faq', {
      url: '/faq'
      views:
        appView:
          templateUrl: '/templates/app/faq.html'
    })
    ... # lots of other states
    .state('account.users.statistics', {
      url: '/:host/:username'
      views:
        statisticsView:
          templateUrl: '/templates/app/_userStatistics.html'
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode true
]
```

However, my code coverage is pretty poor:

Statements: 55.56% (5 / 9)      Branches: 0% (0 / 4)      Functions: 50% (1 / 2)      Lines: 100% (5 / 5)      Ignored: none

What can I do to improve my code coverage?

Comment: Why not exclude this file from coverage reports? Testing config seems pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it('should test routeProvider', function() {
    inject(function($route) {
        expect($route.routes['/faq'].controller).toBe('faqCtrl');
        expect($route.routes['/faq'].templateUrl).toEqual('/templates/app/faq.html');
    });
});
```

You can test like this.
My code is written in angularjs, so I tested like that only using jasmine framework. Sorry, I don't have knowledge in coffescript,